# Function returning null as response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an a closure by Amazon webservices called lambda function with delegation defined as following:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Ev° %s', event)

    if event['action'] == "getPosition":
        getPosition(event, context)

def getPosition(event, context):

    # read position from file
    positionLoaded = readPosition(pId=int(json.loads(str(event['body']['id']))))

    # build response
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(positionLoaded, indent=4),
        "message": "OK",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
    }

return response


# Reads position in json file from s3 Bucket with pId
def readPosition(pId: int):
    positionFromBucketJSON = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="bucketName", Key=str(pId) + ".json")
    return json.loads(positionFromBucketJSON['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

When I send a **request to the lambda function** as following:

```
{
  "action": "getPosition",
  "body": {
    "id": 2021152530123456
  }
}
```

I get an error **response from the lambda function** as following:

```
    {
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
null
```

I don't know why since JSON-File **2021152530123456.json** do exist directly in s3 bucket.

Could you help to figure out what the error could be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Lambda Handler Return Statement

Your lambda_handler is missing a return statement and therefore returning None.   As per the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html)

> If the handler returns None, as Python functions without a return statement implicitly do, the runtime returns null.

I believe you need to return `getPosition(event, context)` as follows

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('Ev° %s', event)

    if event['action'] == "getPosition":
        return getPosition(event, context)
```